# Printing taxonomy terms as an un-ordered list

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

How to print taxonomy terms as an un-ordered list in `page.tpl.php`. Where i want to print a taxonomy term called "Article Category" and all its vocabularies one by one as a un-ordered list, so it can be used as a menu. Can't understand, please give me ideas?

- **EDIT:** I know about a module "[Taxonomy Menu](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu)" but looking for a programmatic direction, idea or any kind of reference that will help me to get started.

Thanks

Comment: Hi rakibtg, are you looking to have the list display as a menu in-site, or just populate a php array to use however you want??

Comment: Hey rakibtg, do you want to display taxonomy terms as menu to your site

Comment: @KyleM i want to print it as a list to use it as a menu. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

OK, there is a module for that! [Taxonomy Menu](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu). Once installed, you can quite simply turn your vocabulary into a menu by going to admin > structure > taxonomy > {your vocabulary} > edit

You can also play around with it and get multi-level menus, which I think is what you are after/asking for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That module seems to be great, but i was looking for a programmatic solution. Thanks for that :)

Comment: Ah sorry for that, how about reverse engineering the code from that Module and using that??

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu. This module helps you print any taxonomy vocabulary as menu. More details from the module's project page:

> - Custom Menu per vocabulary
> - Uses the default taxonomy term path or custom paths
> - Integrate with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)
> - Integrate with [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto): use URL/path aliases
> - Does not interfere with other menu modules

Answer (score 1):

I pulled this from [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7):

```
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree(1); // Use the correct vocabulary id.

// Get the active trail tid-s.
$active = arg(2);
$active_parents = taxonomy_get_parents_all($active);
$active_parents_tids = array();
foreach ($active_parents as $parent) {
  $active_parents_tids[] = $parent->tid;
}

// Build the menu.
$term_count = count($terms);
$cont = '<ul class="taxonomy_menu">';
for ($i = 0; $i < $term_count; $i++) {
  // Build the classes string.
  $classes = '';
  $children = taxonomy_get_children($terms[$i]->tid);
  $active_trail = in_array($terms[$i]->tid, $active_parents_tids);
  if ($active_trail && $children) $classes .= 'expanded active-trail ';
  elseif ($active_trail) $classes .= 'active-trail ';
  elseif ($children) $classes .= 'collapsed ';

  if ($i == 0) $cont .= '<li class="first '.$classes.'">'.l($terms[$i]->name, 'taxonomy/term/'.$terms[$i]->tid);
  else {
    if ($terms[$i]->depth == $depth) $cont .= '</li><li class="'.$classes.'">'.l($terms[$i]->name, 'taxonomy/term/'.$terms[$i]->tid);
    elseif ($terms[$i]->depth > $depth) $cont .= '<ul class="level-'.$terms[$i]->depth.'"><li class="first '.$classes.'">'.l($terms[$i]->name, 'taxonomy/term/'.$terms[$i]->tid);
    elseif ($terms[$i]->depth < $depth) {
      // Add missing end-tags depending of depth level difference.
      for ($j = $terms[$i]->depth; $j < $depth; $j++) {
        $cont .= '</li></ul>';
      }
      $cont .= '</li><li class="'.$classes.'">'.l($terms[$i]->name, 'taxonomy/term/'.$terms[$i]->tid);
    }
    // If we have reached the last element add all possibly missing end-tags.
    if (!isset($terms[$i+1])) {
      for ($j = 0; $j < $terms[$i]->depth; $j++) {
        $cont .= '</li></ul>';
      }
    }
  }
  $depth = $terms[$i]->depth;
}
$cont .= '</li></ul>';
```

Finding the $vid can be a bit tricky, start with 1 and go from there.

Comment: Things are now started :) let you know, my updates ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think Views is the right and the best way to go. There are lots of tutorials on net about this; but if you need help please ask.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are looking to print the taxonomy term for the page, below is the code you can place it in your page.tpl.

```
<?php   
foreach($node->taxonomy as $tid => $taxo)
   $taxo_links[] = l($taxo->name,"taxonomy/term/$taxo->tid", array('title' => $taxo->name));
print t('Located : '). implode('  >  ',$taxo_links);
 ?>
```